# Why was this suggested edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I had placed a suggested edit to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720926/create-a-template-product-video-and-and-change-the-images-and-text-programatical

Here is [the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5301969).

Now the problem:

1. I read the original question and thought I understood it fully, but
   shockingly the question was put on hold. I think, just because of
   someone whoever tried to read the question was unable to understand
   the question, possibly due to a lack of relevant knowledge.
2. I stepped forward and thought I would make it easier to understand
   with a few examples. If is not understandable for the people who are
   interested to answer the question, because though I had understand
   the question, probably because I am in need of the same thing for
   many years, the asker has asked but still I have no answer to the
   question otherwise I would have already given the answer, right?
3. My suggested edit was rejected by three reviewers out of four. I was
   unable to find the words Adobe After Effects in a single of the
   reviewer, still I thanks to one who has accepted, I am pretty sure,
   that person has the knowledge of Adobe After Effects. But the other
   three have vast experience of programming in JavaScript, .NET, etc.

   Still if they have no knowledge of Adobe After Effects then at least
   I can't expect from them a correct answer even though they may be
   most senior programmers and yes definitely we also need programming
   to solve our issue, but **how can a programmer who has no knowledge
   of  Adobe After Effects answer this question**?

   How can a lawyer prescribe you medicine? How can a doctor create a
   design of some building?

   People who do not understand the question or have no answer to the
   question because of their own inability or lack of knowledge, have
   no right to write an answer or review some suggested edit.

   Still I also am a programmer, anyone can see my profile, but you
   would definitely need to understand Adobe After Effects as well.

This review was unjustified and there should be a way of stopping these people from writing answers or reviewing these posts.

Comment: Avoid SHOUTING !!

Comment: If that truly was the most shocking day of your life you have led a very very sheltered life indeed.

Comment: They're not answering the question, so mentioning that seems like irrelevant noise. Reviewing suggested edits has absolutely nothing to do with subject knowledge, unless the subject in question is "How does Stack Overflow work and what makes an acceptable edit?" If the end result is that about two thirds of the post is new content that you've added yourself, expect that to be rejected every single time. You've also not corrected any of the mistakes in what he's written, you've just made it a block quote.

Comment: You should simply not have edited the question in the first place as it was too broad; and your edit couldn't possibly change that. All you did was add more noise with your substantial rewording of the question, which is of course an invalid edit. Please learn about what types of questions are on-topic for StackOverflow, you might find that "SHOCKING" as well.

Comment: Also, the person who approved your edit appears to be the most active in Java-related tags -- not a single Adobe-related tag in sight. So how are you "pretty sure, that person has the knowledge of Adobe After Effects"? How do you know they aren't a robo-reviewer approving bad edits? Not to mention you ignore the possibility that perhaps the people who rejected your edit knew After Effects, and rejected your edit anyways because that was what was expected of them. Good job in ignoring your reviewer's tags when it suits you. I sense some bias...

Comment: @user3580294 so otherwise (not I am saying, but only you) that the person who has accepted is blind or otherwise has accepted the asnwer without reading it? Then OK may be? but again this is your negative assumption about some reviewer.

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I'm saying that you're assuming that the three reviewers are wrong, and the one reviewer is right, when it's *entirely possible that it's the other way around*. It's *possible* that the reviewer accepted without reading (that's called "robo-reviewing", and has been covered many times on MSO), but I'm not saying that that's definitely what happened. Your question is based on the "negative assumption about some reviewer"; I'm just asking why do you ignore the possibility of things going the other way around?

Comment: In short: you assume that the three reviewers who rejected your edit did so because they had no idea what they were reading, and the one who approved has After Effects experience, understood your edit and so approved. I'm asking *how do you know that that is the case*? Do you *know* that the reviewers who rejected did so because they didn't have experience? How do you know that that was actually their reject reason? And how do you know that the person who approved your edit has After Effects experience and approved because of that experience? You're making a lot of claims with no evidence...

Comment: @user3580294, thanks for your nice reply, rarely found in above comments from other people, very shortly, I expect my problem to be solved by the person who has relevant field of knowledge mentioned in his profile, otherwise how can I find solution to my problem.

Comment: and finally please, clearly tell me, I am anxious to learn that, If I have such a genuine problem waiting for some solution, (may be I am not easily able to understand the broad question or whatever the reason of rejection being told.) is that mean that I am have no right to ask the question at all otherwise everyone will yell on me or punish me or how/where can I solve the problem?

Comment: Really sorry but I am afraid that there may be allegation that your comments are broad.

Comment: @AhmedNaveed My apologies, but I'm having a difficult time understanding exactly what you mean, and I'm not very sure where this problem came from. Are you talking about a question that's unrelated to this Meta post? Are you saying that someone's going to solve your problem, but you want to post about it anyways? And you always have the *right* to ask the question; whether it will be received well depends on what exactly it is and how you word it. And what do you mean my comments are broad?

Comment: Very shortly, this would be of satisfaction for me if I may know that, what exactly meanings of broad question? because in my understanding, if any question is out of solution for the experts or reviewers then that question should be marked as broad question.

Comment: Dear @user3580294 my exact problem is about the suggested edit or that question, that can you tell me where I can find its solution, if this should be rightly rejected on stackoverflow. My expectations were really high with stackoverflow but after the result of my suggested edit I understand now that there may be some problem existing of which solution is nowhere existing in the world including stackoverlow.

Comment: My dear friend! just towards the closure of the discussion, I exactly want to know, if stackoverflow can not help me understand/answer my question/suggested edit, then is there not any other possibility where I can have answer to my question?

Comment: The definition of a "broad question" is usually decided on a case-by-case basis, but a good rule of thumb is that if you can write a book, series of tutorials, etc. about the answer, then it's too broad. Just because no one posted an answer does not mean that the question is too broad; it just means that no one posted an answer. You can have very specific questions that don't have an answer (e.g. I came across this behavior in the Java compiler, is this a bug?), and you can have too broad questions that people try to answer (e.g. I want to do X, Y, and Z, how do I do it?).

Comment: The solution has already been given in the answers to your question. Your suggested edit was correct in being rejected, but that is not the same thing as the question having no answer; they are two separate issues. The fact that you think of that question as "your" question is telling; you have to remember that this was a question asked by *someone else*, and you need to respect that. If you think you can write that question better than the asker of that question did, and if you can make it substantially better, then I suggest you try asking a question of your own.

Comment: Thanks dear, I hope I am clear now. This was actually the basic difference just like I quoted the same question in suggested edit, that was respect for the asker in my point-of-view, where as, you suggested me to write my own question to maintain the respect level of the asker. Sorry for my behaviour of quouting and then entirely changing the original question, if that was the basic problem. That was unknowingly because I thought that the question is same as I want to ask and I can make it easy to understand with example. But everything went opposite.

Comment: Now can I copy and paste my entire suggested edit in a new question (excluding the quoted question). I mean due to any reason there should not be any problem in doing that. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you know After Effects or not. It doesn't matter whether the reviewers know After Effects.

The point is: you made an edit which dramatically changed the question.

So it was rejected.

**Don't take it personally**. Learn from it (and from the responses here) and try to make better edits in future.

Comment: Thanks to some reasonable, nice and logical answer. I am definitely in the learning process continually so I was on this site. Now can you suggest me if it is not against the policies of the site that where I can ask such question that I feel need some answer.

Comment: What do you mean Ahmed?

Comment: Simply I want to ask that if the question readers/reviewers have not enough space in there mind to accommodate my question/suggested edit (though due to any reason like "broad question") then is that means I can never have answer to my question? or can you tell me what should I do next to find the answer to my question/suggested edit.

Comment: Because I still believe that my suggested edit needs some solution though it may not be according to the rules of site.

Comment: Ahmed, no, edits must not make such major changes. That sort of thing is not welcome. It is not anything to do with 'not having enough space in their mind' - which men's nothing and is just patronising. Your edit breaks the question. If you want to ask a different question, then ask it as a new question.

Comment: So would you suggest me to simply copy my suggested edit in a new question, or I suspect there may be some other problem (may be like **the question already posted in suggested edit**, or like **broad question**)?

Comment: Ahmed - if your question is sufficiently different, yes, ask it as a new question. If not, you can't use a suggested edit to change an existing question in any major way. This is all covered in the faq and help pages. **please read them**

Answer (score 18):

It is up to Michael to format his question such that it is legible and understandable, **not** yours (regardless of your best intention).

Your edit does **not** stop the post being too broad. You are effectively smearing lipstick on a pig, and unfortunately, wasting your time by making the edit, and the reviewers time by making them review it. Invest your good time in improving *better* posts than Michael's.

Your edit itself puts a **lot** of words in Michael's mouth. Where are you getting the idea of ID cards, being prompted for name's etc from? This is a **radical change**. It was right to be rejected.

Comment: Comparing a question by a SO user to a pig is maybe not the nicest way.

Comment: @Trilarion "putting lipstick on a pig" is a common colloquial term for a pointless task.  It's stretching pretty hard to be offended by it.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, never heard of it before, I'm not offended anymore.

Comment: The formatting abuse (_quoting_ the original text of the question?!) would also be enough to reject the edit, even if all the material was strictly appropriate.